# Basic Socket.io connection with swift

Tags: swift, sockets, socket.io

Trying to wrap my head around socket.io and sockets in general by trying simple swift test app. If I open connection/socket with **telnet** to address **83.145.232.209 8080** and after that send message like **'&okffin;tuusula1 id:RHKL00233&'** the server side starts to push messages to me.

Now I'm trying to get that happening with socket.IO in swift. I tried following simple test.

```
@IBAction func liveTest(sender: NSButton) {
     socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "83.145.232.209:8080", options: [.Log(true)])
     socket!.onAny {print("Got event: \($0.event), with items: \($0.items)")}
     socket!.emit("&okffin;tuusula1 id:RHKL00233&", "")
     socket!.connect()
}
```

However I'm not able to get connection or any data back from the server with this. Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding on this or am I just configuring the client wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After reading up more on sockets and socket.io I can answer my own question by saying I had fundamental misunderstanding on socket.io. Socket.io is only meant for communication over web (http) for apps built on engine.io.

What I need and my example called for is 'regular' socket over tcp and I found [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to be perfect for that job.

Answer (score 0):

### Please try this it's working for me.

```
 let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL:NSURL(string:"http://:8080")!, options: [.Log(true), .ForcePolling(true)])

    socket.on("connect")
            {data, ack in
               print("socket connected")
                self.addHandlers()
            }
     socket.connect()

func addHandlers()
    {
        let myJSON : String!
        myJSON = "{\"userKey\":931234567890 \"countryCode\":93\"mobileNo\":1234567890}"
        self.socket.emit("register user step1", myJSON)
        self.socket.onAny {print("Got event: \($0.event), with items: \($0.items)")}

    }
```